# Escape a space in a file path in Node.js

Tags: javascript

I receive a file path string via `JSON.parse`, but I need to escape the spaces in the string with backslashes.

How should I do this idiomatically in Node.js?

For example:

```
var input = JSON.parse('{ "path": "/foo/bar bam/baz.html" }');
input.path.replace(/(\s)/g, '\\$1');
```

Comment: What's wrong with that `.replace()` call? (other than the fact that the code doesn't save the result)

Comment: Should be:  `input.path.replace(/\s+/g, '\\$1');`

Comment: @ScottMarcus depending on the reason for the escaping, that may not work. For example, Linux shell syntax requires every space be individually quoted.

Comment: I was concerned that manually adding backslashes would not perform the escaping I wanted and might result in double escaping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```js
var input = JSON.parse('{ "path": "/foo/bar bam/baz.html" }');

console.log(input.path.replace(/(\s+)/g, '\\$1'));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but next time, please explain what you did and why this works but the op's doesn't

Comment: In fact, still do that, even if it's years later.

Comment: Chrome dev console returns '/foo/bar\\ bam/baz.html'  as a result (with two slashes). Sandbox above returns '/foo/bar\ bam/baz.html'